# What should I do in QT designer to achieve the same functionality as QBoxLayout :: addStretch?

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer

I would like to achieve in the Qt designer addStretch function, but I did not find any way in this way.

Comment: Add a spacer to the end of the layout,

Comment: Only some properties are exposed in Qt Designer, so if not you should do so by code.

Answer (score -1):

Change the `Layout.layoutStretch` in the Property Editor in the Qt Designer.
You may set the values of the `layoutStretch` from `"0,0,0"` to `"1,0,0"` if you want to stretch the first item when you have three rows or columns.